# Android Studio 2 + Maven?

Tags: maven, android-studio-2.2

Can I use maven with Android Studio? I have heard otherwise, but cant really believe it.
Since it doesnt seem to work with the default setup, I wonder if there is a way to make maven work with Android Studio2?